# Irremovable folder after wiping free space with bleach bit

Tags: filesystem, delete, bleachbit

I have a following problem. Yesterday I was using Bleach Bit as root to wipe free space. When I woke up Bleach Bit was not Responding and the terminal hangs on "suffix length = 235". So I force Bleach Bit to stop. After reboot I have noticed that there is 4GB folder at my home directory.

When I'm trying to remove it with

```
sudo rm -rf 'iJ5soqs a3'
```

Terminal hangs, same issue when I'm trying to open it or using file browser instead of terminal or in recovery mode.

Is there anyway to get rid of this folder.

@Andrew:
You are right, I was using 1.0 version of Bleach Bit. However I could bet that I'm deleting this folder incorrectly because simply nothing happens, as I said terminal hangs on removing. `df -i` command shows no change. In task manager I can see that terminal uses very little memory and no CPU. Command have been running for about 4 hours and still nothing happens.

Edit2:
After 5 hours it finally gets deleted I must admit that I'm pleasantly surprised.

Comment: I think you want `sudo rm -rf "iJ5soqs a3"`

Comment: It doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are using a version of BleachBit older than version 1.2, right?  If so, there are maybe a million empty files in this folder.

You are deleting this folder correctly, you just need to wait much longer because deleting files is slow on Linux.

You can watch the progress using the command `df -i`, which shows inodes usage.

[BleachBit 1.2](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/news/bleachbit-12), release a year ago, prevents this problem, but Ubuntu does not update BleachBit except with updates of Ubuntu. (For example, Ubuntu 14.04 will update to BleachBit 1.6, but Ubuntu 13.10 will never have BleachBit 1.6.) You can download the latest version (1.6) from [BleachBit.sourceforge.net](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/).